# Type '"account_onboarding"' is not assignable to type 'Type'.ts in stripe api on typescript nodejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

How do i do this in stripe? with apiVersion: '2020-03-02'

> The type of account link the user is requesting. Possible values are
> custom_account_verification or custom_account_update.
>
> Type '"account_onboarding"' is not assignable to type 'Type'.ts(2322)
> AccountLinks.d.ts(37, 7): The expected type comes from property 'type'
> which is declared here on type 'AccountLinkCreateParams'

```
const generateAccountLink = async (accountID:string, origin:string) => {
    return stripe.accountLinks.create({
      type: "account_onboarding",
      account: accountID,
      refresh_url: `${origin}/`,
      return_url: `${origin}/`,
    }).then((link) => link.url);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `AccountLinks.d.ts` you have matches the API version you are using? If it comes from a npm package, perhaps check that package's description for compatibility information.

Comment: arh yes need to use 'apiVersion: '2020-08-27''